# Hide object in decorator.rb - Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

My company had an app developed months ago but are only starting to use it now.  The developer has since left.  I'm a part of the technical team, but not a developer and have been asked to resolve an issue.

We have an app the displays properties.  When adding a property, the user can choose to show or hide the address on the map.  If they show the address, then the map has a pop-up with shows the full address ( 2468 Anystreet, State, Country).  If they choose to hide it, the map pin is still in the correct location and the address pop-up should show just City, State, Country.

The problem is that anytime a property is added with the "hide" option chosen, all the hidden properties bunch up on the same pin at the same location.

I'm able to correct this issue by adding the longitude and latitude to location_decorator.rb.

```
  def address
    if object.hidden?
      [object.city, object.state, object.country, object.longitude, object.latitude].select(&:present?).join(', ')
    else
      object.address
    end
  end
```

The probelem with this fix is that the longitude and latitude show up on the map pin pop-up next to City, State, Country.

**Is there a way to not display latitude and longitude?  Can these objects be hidden within this code?**

I appreciate your help.

Comment: `[object.city, object.state, object.country].select(&:present?).join(', ')` ? And what do you mean by "_all the hidden properties bunch up on the same pin at the same location._"? Could you also show the model code?

Comment: Where do you send those params?